# Django test database isn't deleted after test completion when running a process

Tags: python, django, subprocess, pytest, pytest-django

**Background**

[Django-pgpubsub](https://github.com/Opus10/django-pgpubsub) listens for PostgresSQL triggers by running
`python manage.py listen`. This command continuously runs and serves as a lightweight alternative to Django signals and celery for sending emails when a Shipment model instance's status field changes to certain values.

**Problem**

***Update***

This works with `--reuse-db` (workaround found on [this pytest-django issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/429)). But it would be nice not to rely on this workaround.

The integration test calls the `python manage.py listen` command in a separate process using `subprocess`. The test passes but the test database remains and I have to manually delete it after to prevent the next test from failing due to a duplicate database. Whatever teardown functionality that comes with `django-pytest` is being called since this outputs upon test completion:

`Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_my_project_database')`

**The Test**

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True) # needed to work
def test_shipment_status_notifications_with_listen_command_subprocess(testuser):
    user = testuser
    # model instances setup for the test
    notification_settings = NotificationSettings.objects.get(user=user)
    notification_settings.failed_attempt = True
    notification_settings.save()
    cust_email = "test@test.com"
    customer = Customer.objects.create(email=cust_email)
    order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer)
    shipment = Shipment.objects.create(user=user, order=order)

    listen_command = [
        "python",
        str(settings.ROOT_DIR / "manage.py"),
        "listen",
    ]
    env = os.environ.copy()
    # we need to update these env vars to use the actual test database instead of the live one
    # the process uses the live database by default
    env.update(
        {
            "DATABASE_URL":
                f"postgresql://{config('POSTGRES_USER')}:{config('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')}@127.0.0.1:5432/test_{config('POSTGRES_DB')}",
        }
    )

    listen_process = subprocess.Popen(
        listen_command,
        env=env,
    )
    time.sleep(2)  # confirmed needed
    # Change Shipment status to trigger the notification
    shipment.status = Shipment.FAILED_ATTEMPT
    shipment.save()

    time.sleep(2)  # confirmed needed
    listen_process.terminate()

    existing_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(
        type=Notification.Type.FAILED_DELIVERY_ATTEMPT,
        shipment=shipment,
        email=cust_email,
    )
    print(f"existing_notifications: {existing_notifications}")
    assert existing_notifications.count() == 1
```

**What I've Tried**

Deleting the database using a pytest fixture (calling SQL commands after `yield` so it's included in the test's teardown) results in the built-in `pytest-django` teardown exception about "connection already closed/doesn't exist".

Answer (score 0):

Using the `--reuse-db` pytest flag works and the test passes in CI. The source for the fix is from a [pytest-django feature request](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/429#issuecomment-381259636).

For anyone else facing this issue, if notifications pass locally but not in CI, try increasing sleeps before and/or after model instance updates as CI test runners are slower (at least with github CI/CD workflows).